# Image in the top div always hide the bottom div with a negative margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I created two divs with one stacks on top of the other. The top div contains an image which is displayed in block. The bottom div has a negative margin and a background color. However, the background color of the part of the bottom div that overlaps with the top div can not be displayed, although the content in the bottom div is shown on top of the top div. How can I display the background color on top of the top div as well?

The following is the code and the live demo is available from here: http://jsfiddle.net/spencerfeng/6XFau/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="container1">
    <img class="responsive-img" src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/One-Ocean-One-Breath14.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dapibus pretium orci, ac tristique mauris tincidunt sit amet. Vestibulum ornare in felis non fringilla.</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width:300px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#container1 img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#container2 {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Comment: even i don't understand why does this happen? as per the spec regarding stacking context shouldn't the content which comes later in dom overlap the previous elements? since img tag by default has position value of static so any content of static position should overlap img if it comes later in dom. An elaborated anwser would be higly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the red div top overlap the image you should use relative positioning as follows

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CBa2v/)

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:300px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#container1 img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#container2 {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default margin from the p:

```
p{margin:0}
```

and remove the negative margin top from the second div:

```
#container2 {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

The two boxes should align perfectly if that's what you are after

Answer (score -1):

Use these two properties for bottom div:

```
position:relative;
z-index:999999;
```